# Can I add widgets to the new Unity lock screen in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, 14.04, lock-screen, widgets

When I lock my screen using Linux Mint 17, there is a giant clock on the lock screen. I got used to this, and now I'm wondering if I can also add a giant clock (or any widget, for that matter) to my Ubuntu 14.04 lock screen. Is there a way for me to do this with relative ease?

Answer (score 1):

+1 on this: I'm currently working in an environment where you need to lock your workspace if you're not at your desk, but I have reporting stuff going to a second monitor. It'd be a neat workaround if I could just load a webpage as a widget so people could still see that even if my screen is locked.